# How to center table cells and remove a gap near the java swing JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

The JTable is expected to be the implementation of the Pac-Man game board, therefore the cells of the table are squared. The scalability of the table should also be considered. The problem is that if in the JPanel I use BorderLayout the table is scalable, but aligned to the left and when the BorderLayout is not passed to the JPanel constructor, the table is centered but not scalable.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

public class Game extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game("Table");
    }

    Game(String title) {
        super(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        BoardView b = new BoardView(new Board(36, 28));
        p.add(b);
        add(p);


        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class BoardView extends JTable {
        private Board board;

        public BoardView(Board board) {
            super(board);
            this.board = board;

            setTableHeader(null);
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);

            addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                    int size = Math.min(getHeight() / getRowCount(), getWidth() / getColumnCount());
                    setRowHeight(size);
                    for (int i = 0; i < getColumnCount(); i++) {
                        TableColumn column = getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                        column.setMaxWidth(size);
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    }

    public class Board extends AbstractTableModel {
        private int rows;
        private int columns;
        private int[][] boardData;

        public Board(int rows, int columns) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns;
            this.boardData = new int[rows][columns];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return boardData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            boardData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (int) value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: A JTable is NOT the proper component to use for a game. Do [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) on a JPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Introduction

I'd still create a drawing `JPanel` and draw the boxes rather than bastardize a `JTable` like this.

It took me a while, but I modified the code you posted enough to create the following GUI:

[image: Table 1]

When you expand the frame, the GUI looks like this:

[image: Table 2]

## Explanation

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

All Swing applications must start with a call to the `SwingUtilities` `invokeLater` method.  This method ensures that the Swing components are created and executed on the [Event Dispatch Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html).

I modified your code to use a `JFrame`, `JPanel`, and `JTable`, rather than extend anything.  This gave me more flexibility, allowed me to separate my concerns, and focus on one part of the GUI at a time.

The `JPanel` uses a `BorderLayout`.  By adjusting the margins of an empty border, I was able to center the `JTable` in the `JPanel`.

When constructing the `JPanel` and the `JTable`, I had to calculate the size of the `JTable` and `JPanel` before I could construct the GUI.  This is why the `JPanel` has a size calculation method and the `ComponentAdapter` has a separate size calculation.

I created a separate `ComponentAdapter` class just so I could get the code out of the `JPanel` class.

## Code

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post the code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

public class JTableLayout {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new JTableLayout("Table");
            }
        });
    }

    private JTable table;

    JTableLayout(String title) {
        Board board = new Board(36, 28);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(new BoardView(board).getPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class BoardView {

        private Board board;

        private JPanel panel;

        public BoardView(Board board) {
            this.board = board;
            this.panel = createJTablePanel();
        }

        private JPanel createJTablePanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

            table = new JTable(board);
            table.setTableHeader(null);
            table.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            table.setPreferredSize(calculateBoardDimension(table));
            panel.add(table);

            panel.addComponentListener(new PanelListener(table, board));
            return panel;
        }

        private Dimension calculateBoardDimension(JTable table) {
            int totalHeight = table.getRowHeight() * board.getRowCount();
            int totalWidth = table.getRowHeight() * board.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                column.setMaxWidth(table.getRowHeight());
            }

            return new Dimension(totalWidth, totalHeight);
        }

        public JPanel getPanel() {
            return panel;
        }

    }

    public class PanelListener extends ComponentAdapter {

        private Board board;

        private JTable table;

        public PanelListener(JTable table, Board board) {
            this.table = table;
            this.board = board;
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) event.getSource();
            Dimension d = panel.getSize();
            int height = d.height / board.getRowCount();
            int width = d.width / board.getColumnCount();

            boolean widthLarger = true;
            int size = height;
            if (size > width) {
                size = width;
                widthLarger = false;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                column.setMaxWidth(size);
            }

            table.setRowHeight(size);

            Border border = panel.getBorder();
            Insets insets = (Insets) border.getBorderInsets(panel);
            if (widthLarger) {
                int boardWidth = board.getColumnCount() * size;
                int margin = (d.width - boardWidth) / 2;
                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(insets.top,
                        margin, insets.bottom, margin));
            } else {
                int boardHeight = board.getRowCount() * size;
                int margin = (d.height - boardHeight) / 2;
                panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(margin,
                        insets.left, margin, insets.right));
            }
        }

    }

    public class Board extends AbstractTableModel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private int rows;
        private int columns;
        private int[][] boardData;

        public Board(int rows, int columns) {
            this.rows = rows;
            this.columns = columns;
            this.boardData = new int[rows][columns];
        }

        @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows;
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return columns;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            return boardData[rowIndex][columnIndex];
        }

        @Override
        public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            boardData[rowIndex][columnIndex] = (int) value;
            fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
        }
    }
}
```